# Outputting a Matrix inside of a Playa field

Tags: matrix, templates, playa

I've found a couple other posts regarding same issue, but can't seem to resolve with any solutions out there.

Everything is outputting fine except content in tag pair `{studies_outline_block}`, which is a matrix field inside a playa field inside of a matrix field.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>     

{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
    {studies_projects}
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="project-box ">
                <img src="{image}" alt="{cat_name} category image">
                <h3>{cat_name}</h3>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {playa_projects}
                    <?php $count = $i++; ?>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline-<?php echo $count; ?>" title="{studies_caption}">{title}</a></li>
                    <div id="inline-<?php echo $count; ?>" style="display:none;">
                        <div id="slider<?php echo $count; ?>" class="flexslider slider-js">
                            <div class="flex-heading">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h2>{project_name}</h2>
                                </div>
                                {studies_outline_block}
                                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                                            <h3>Project Size</h3>
                                            {content_1}
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                                            <h3>Project Cost</h3>
                                            {content_2}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                                            <h3>Project Use</h3>
                                            {content_3}
                                        </div>
                                {/studies_outline_block}
                            </div>
                            <ul class="slides">
                                {studies_image_gallery}
                                    <li><img src="{url}" /></li>
                                {/studies_image_gallery}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel<?php echo $count; ?>" class="flexslider carousel-js">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                {studies_image_gallery}
                                    <li><img src="{url}" /></li>
                                {/studies_image_gallery}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {/playa_projects}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {/studies_projects}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the var_prefix parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve using the var_prefix parameter. Here's the correct code:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>     

{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" dynamic="off"}
    {studies_projects}
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="project-box ">
                <img src="{image}" alt="{cat_name} category image">
                <h3>{cat_name}</h3>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {playa_projects var_prefix="playafield"}
                    <?php $count = $i++; ?>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline-<?php echo $count; ?>" title="{studies_caption}">{playafield:title}</a></li>
                    <div id="inline-<?php echo $count; ?>" style="display: none;">
                        <div id="slider<?php echo $count; ?>" class="flexslider slider-js">
                            <div class="flex-heading">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h2>{playafield:project_name}</h2>
                                </div>
                                {playafield:studies_outline_block var_prefix="nested_matrix"}
                                    {if nested_matrix:content_1}
                                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                                            <h3>Project Size</h3>
                                            {nested_matrix:content_1}
                                        </div>
                                    {/if}
                                    {if nested_matrix:content_2}
                                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                                            <h3>Project Cost</h3>
                                            {nested_matrix:content_2}
                                        </div>
                                    {/if}
                                    {if nested_matrix:content_3}
                                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                                            <h3>Project Use</h3>
                                            {nested_matrix:content_3}
                                        </div>
                                    {/if}
                                {/playafield:studies_outline_block}
                            </div>
                            <ul class="slides">
                                {studies_image_gallery}
                                    <li><img src="{playafield:url}" /></li>
                                {/studies_image_gallery}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="carousel<?php echo $count; ?>" class="flexslider carousel-js">
                            <ul class="slides">
                                {studies_image_gallery}
                                    <li><img src="{playafield:url}" /></li>
                                {/studies_image_gallery}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {/playa_projects}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {/studies_projects}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```